# My ListView shows duplicate items whenever I close my app

Tags: android, listview

I am having a problem with my ListView. Whenever I close my app it creates duplicate items and when I run the app the third time it shows me a single item 3 times. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Ok so here is my LazyAdapter Code

```
 @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
     public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {

        return new android.widget.Filter() {

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
                // if constraint is empty return the original names
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)){
                    //Result.values = storedata;
                    Result.count = listDetails.size();
                        return Result;
                }

                ArrayList<items> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<items>();
                String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                String filterableString;

                for(int i = 0; i<listDetails.size(); i++){
                    items searchdata = listDetails.get(i);
                    String title = searchdata.title();
                    String id = searchdata.id();
                    String imageUrl = searchdata.imageUrl();
                    String pprice = searchdata.pprice();
                    String shippingPrice = searchdata.shippingPrice();
                    String stock = searchdata.stock();

                    filterableString = title+" "+id+" "+imageUrl+" "+pprice+"
                   "+shippingPrice+" "+status+" "+stitle+" "+stock+" 
                    if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                        Filtered_Names.add(listDetails.get(i));
                        //Log.e("Added", String.valueOf(Filtered_Names.size()));
                    }

                }
                Result.values = Filtered_Names;
                Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();
                //Log.e("Results", Result.values.toString() +
                    // String.valueOf(Result.count));
                return Result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<items> resultList =(ArrayList<items>) results.values;
                LazyAdapter.this.listDetails = resultList;
                LazyAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }    
        };
    }
```

the constructor in that lazyAdapter

```
public  LazyAdapte(Context context , ArrayList<items> list) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        listDetails = list;
         downloader = new ImageDownloader();
    }
```

And here is the Activity code

```
public class ItemsActivity extends Activity{

    EditText inputsearch;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<items> list;
    Controller control;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_activity);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id._view);

        control = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
        list = (ArrayList<items>) control.Table_items.GetData();
        final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id._data);

        final LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, list);
        adapter.setLayout(this, layout);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputsearch);
    if(adapter!=null){
    }
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, 
             int arg3) {

             try{
                ItemsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
             }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         }
     }); 
 }
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate you query??? what do you mean by *I close my app it creates duplicate items*

Comment: I mean when I get back from my app to any other app and on opening it it shows me new (duplicate) items with the old when

Comment: Does your activity refresh??

Comment: yes i have a refresh task whenever I call to the above (ItemsActivity). just like I have this code in the last actvity `Intent intent = new Intent(Buy.this,ItemsActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);

     RefrashTask task = new RefrashTask();
     task.execute(Constants.MODE_REFRESH);`

Comment: @SweetWisherツ So your second comment worked for me. It pointed me towards the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in getfilter method

you can try
using
 http://software-workshop.eu/content/android-development-creating-custom-filter-listview

or
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html

Comment: no thats not right getfilter is working but thankx for the links you shared. they will help in future.